# python irc client no ident response

Tags: python, sockets, client, response, irc

I am writing an IRC chat client cause my ISP doesn't allow normal IRC programs. so I am making one using SSL. Anyway, I ran my IRC chat client and I can listen fine I just cant Identify myself.  I always receive this after the start of chat.

*** No Ident response

Everything that I have looked at has me listen on port 113 and respond so I wrote a TCP socket to listen and print what is sent, thinking I follow the other recomendations. However, I never get any response and I telneted to the server socket on 113 and I was able to connect and communicate just fine.

I don't think IRC is sending its verification back on 113 or I have something wrong in the information that I am sending. how can myself identified or at least response  to reply to identify myself and chat

Here is my CLIENT:

```
import socket, string, re, time , ssl, urllib

network = 'irc.freenode.net'
nick    = 'testr'
chan    = 'ubuntu'
port    = 7000 #6697

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def main(network, nick, port):
        socket.connect((network,port))
        irc = ssl.wrap_socket(socket)
        irc.send('NICK %s\r\n' % nick)
        print irc.recv(4096)
        irc.send('USER %s %s %s :TEST\r\n' % (nick,nick,nick))
        print irc.recv(4096)
        irc.send("JOIN #%s\r\n" % chan)
        print irc.recv(4096)

        print "STARTING CHAT!!"

        while True:
                data = irc.recv(4096)
                print data
                irc.send("TEST")

                if data.find('PING') != -1:
                        print "PING RECEIVED!"
                        print "SENDING PONG!"
                        irc.send('PONG '+data.split()[1]+'\r\n')

    if __name__=='__main__':
        main(network, nick, port)
```

And my SERVER for testing for response:

```
#!/usr/bin/python           

import socket               
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

host = 'localhost' 
port = 113                 
s.bind((host, port))        
s.listen(5)                 

while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   data = c.recv(1024)
   print data
   #c.close()                # Close the connection
```

Comment: FWIW: google "irc client ssl" to find many that already support SSL.

Answer (score 0):

'ident' means something other than what you're thinking. It's actually a service that has to meet a specific protocol. (However, most IRC servers aren't strict about it..)

Odds are you'll need to setup a NAT port forward from your external address to your fake ident server to support this. 99% of the world will be setup with an external address that you could telnet to port 113 of, and it won't connect to anything unless your firewall is configured correctly.

However, you can in most cases ignore ident - it's basically garbage anyway. The remote connection is trusting you to confirm the identity of the user who's using the local host ports.. which, is untrustworthy to say the least. For this reason, most ircd's may check it for historical reasons but hardly any will penalize you for having fake data.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol for more information.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was curious , is this the reason I cannot speak in chat? I had an alternative of the code that allowed me to irc.send("STRING") but that never sent data tot he server or atleast anything that anyone could see.